# Alinear imagen a la izquierda y texto a la derecha con fondo incluido html

Tags: html, css

estoy tratando de alinear una imagen a la izquierda y ponerle texto a la derecha, he intentado con

```
float:left
```

Por lo que logro alinearla pero el texto de la derecha empieza en el pie de la foto y quiero que empiece desde el principio de la foto dejando algun margen

Tambien en el div de la imagen y el texto , he agregado un fondo para la imagen y el texto, pero solo sigue la longitud del texto.

Alguien podria ayudarme con eso.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <style>

.item-image {
  background-image: url("bkgd.jpg");
  background-color: #cccccc;
  float:left;
}

body {background-color: powderblue;}
h1   {color: blue;}
b    {color: red;}
</style> 
 </head>
 <body>

    <div class="item item-image">
<img src="<?= $_POST['imghide']; ?>" />Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado 
     </div>
<br clear="all">
</body>
</html>
```

Imagen [image: Imagen del resultado]

Gracias asi ha quedado ahora:

```
  <style>
.item-image {
  background-image: url("fondo5.jpg");
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border: red 2px solid;
}
.imagepadding {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
p {
  margin: 10px;
  padding-right: 300px;
}     
b    {color: blue;}
</style>
<div id="poster" class="item-image">    
<img id="image" align="left" class="imagepadding" src="<?= $_POST['imghide']; ?>" />
<p id="a-code-snippet">
<b> Pelicula:</b> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?><br>
</p>   
<br clear="all">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas poniendo el texto dentro de la caja de la imagen. Ponlo fuera del div de la imagen y ponle una etiqueta

al texto a ver si te funciona.

```
 <div class="item item-image">
<img src="<?= $_POST['imghide']; ?>" />
     </div>
<p>Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado </p>
```

Comment: Gracias mi amigo, me ha funcionado perfecto Te agradezco la ayuda